# XSLT Self Closing Tags WITH style

Tags: html, xslt

I'm writing some XSLT to render the output of a Rich Text Box in an infopath form.

Occasionally I'll get something like this in the output:

"<span style="font-size: 11px" class="Apple-style-span" />"

And it breaks EVERYTHING. I can't use:

<xsl:if test="string(.) != '' or descendant-or-self::*/@*[string(.)]">

because technically it isn't empty. What are my options?

Comment: Trying to understand the exact issue, it is because it is self closing and if it has a closure </... it works ok?

Comment: Please explain: 1) what is breaking, and how? 2) what do you mean "technically it isn't empty"? _Empty-element tags_ (which is the official name for a tag in XML that closes with "/>") are indeed empty in the sense that they have no string value: string(.) will evaluate to '' or false.

Answer (score 2):

If you're getting `<span style="font-size: 11px" class="Apple-style-span" />` from xslt, you've got the xslt output mode set to xml instead of html.